# Using Config::Simple to read MySQL config file with keys without values

Tags: perl, perl-module

I try to configure my mySql config file with perl. 
I use config::simple for doing this.
my code is:

```
#!/bin/perl
use Config::Simple;

$cfg = new Config::Simple('/etc/mysql/my.cnf');
$cfg->param('bind-address', '192.168.1.11');
$cfg->save();
```

the problem is that I get an error when a row only has a key and not an value to it. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: The format of my.cnf doesn't really fit with any of the things that Config::Simple can read/write. I think you're out of luck unless you write your own compatibility layer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extend [simbabque's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724578/perl-configsimple-how-to-read-files-with-keys-without-values/39724768#comment66746535_39724578) I would suggest using [Config::MySQL](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::MySQL) to deal with MySQL config files.

> Config::MySQL extends Config::INI to support reading and writing
>   MySQL-style configuration files. Although deceptively similar to
>   standard .INI files, they can include bare boolean options **with no
>   value assignment** and additional features like !include and
>   !includedir.

Comment: I just started writing a monkey patch for Config::Simple. I guess I can stop. xD

Comment: @simbabque: Ha! :)